# How to speed up working with Sparse Arrays

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays

I make a `SparseArray` and then modify it by adding rows together. This seems to take a long time. Can it be speeded up?

```
na = 1000;
nb = 60000;
nc = 50;
c = 0.8;
data = Flatten[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {na, na}]];
loc = RandomInteger[{1, 5386/2}, {na^2, 2}];
mat = SparseArray[loc -> data, {nb, nb}, 0.0];
ri = RandomInteger[{1, nb/2}, nc];
```

Now to do the adding of rows. This is what takes the time.

```
Timing[Do[mat[[n]] = mat[[n]] + c mat[[nb/2 + n]],
   {n, ri}];]
```

This takes 1.09 seconds on my machine Version; 11.3. Could it be done faster? Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Put as many operations as possible into one call:

```
mat[[ri]] += c mat[[nb/2 + ri]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.010061

**Edit**

I also thought about a more general situation where rows enumerated by a list `readidx` are read from an input matrix, multiplied by a factor, and then added to rows enumerated by a `writeidx`. If `readidx` or `writeidx` contains any duplicates, one can create a lower triangular matrix to achieve the goal much quicker than with the `Do` loop:

```
SeedRandom[666];
nnz = 100000;
nb = 60000;
nc = 5000;

data = Flatten[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, nnz]];
loc = RandomInteger[{1, nb}, {nnz, 2}];
A = mat0 = SparseArray[loc -> data, {nb, nb}, 0.0];
readidx = RandomInteger[{1, nb}, nc];
writeidx = RandomInteger[{1, nb}, nc];
factors = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, nc];
DuplicateFreeQ[readidx]
DuplicateFreeQ[writeidx]
```

> False
>
> False

```
B1 = A;
Do[B1[[writeidx[[i]]]] += factors[[i]] A[[readidx[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[readidx]}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

B2 = With[{L = With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
        Internal`WithLocalSettings[
         SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}],
         SparseArray[
          Transpose[{writeidx, readidx}] -> factors, 
          {Length[A], Length[A]}
         ],
         SetSystemOptions[spopt]]
        ]},
     A + L.A
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
B1 == B2
```

> 18.1406
>
> 0.008159
>
> True

Note that we have to `SetSystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}]` so that the matrix `L` gets assempled correctly, even if `Transpose[{writeidx, readidx}]` contains duplicates.

Comment: How do I get the times c into it?

Comment: This is wonderful. I have implemented in my code. Now a calculation that took 30 seconds takes 0.03 seconds. A factor of 1000. Your further problem is also enlightening. This is the second time you have helped me in 24 hours.  Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that! You're always welcome!